# Relative path for client hook script settings

Tags: tortoisesvn

I'm trying to create a client hook script for TortoiseSVN 1.8.11 on Windows 7.
What is givining me trouble is the path to the hook script in the settings (Settings->Hook Scripts).

Using the absolute path to my batch script works, but I need to use a path relative to the repository. The reason for this is that coworkers might have their repositories in different locations and the hook script should be used by everybody. Server side hooks are out of the question, since I can't modify the server.

I tried using environment variables, `^/my/path/hook.bat` and `^^/my/path/hook.bat`, no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Client-side hooks are **local executables**, not related in any way to your local *Working Copy* (not repository)
2. TortoiseSVN's configuration, performed using `TortoiseSVN` - `Settings`, not stored in WC|repository and also is **pure local**

If you want to have any client-side hooks avaliable and callable for everybody in team (with *TortoiseSVN only*), you have

- Place these scripts **into repository**
- Define all hooks as folder-properties **in repository**. Read about

  - tsvn:startcommithook
  - tsvn:precommithook
  - tsvn:postcommithook
  - tsvn:startupdatehook
  - tsvn:preupdatehook
  - tsvn:postupdatehook

properties and parameters and about using special wariables (`%REPOROOT%` and `%REPOROOT+%`) in script-path in TSVN help, part "4.17.2. TortoiseSVN Project Properties"

Comment: Is there a way to check what %REPOROOT% contains? From my tests %REPOROOT%\trunk\...\hook.bat and %REPOROOT%/trunk/.../hook.bat dont even produce an error message. echo %REPOROOT% > C:\Users\Joe\test.txt doesn't produce a text file at all.

Comment: @red_rain - OMFG, `echo %REPOROOT%` in hook. But don't forget to redirect output in order to see it (or use redirect to file)

Comment: @red_rain - I'm too lazy to test it, but my POV - for %REPOROOT% must be used the same value as shown in Repository Root key in `svn info`

Comment: @Lazy_Badger echo %REPOROOT% > con  and echo %REPOROOT+% > con result in ECHO is on. Apparently REPOROOT is not accessible for the hook script.

Comment: @Lazy_Badger I figured it out now, your answer is spot on. Due to doing work in parallel I misread some parts. Thank you for sticking with me.